# "You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access" after running through all the ssh setup steps

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

I'm so confused. I'm trying to get the `git clone` command working, but it keeps saying:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I feel I have done all the correct steps, though.

1- I've installed git. When I do `git --version` it says `git version 2.17.1`.

2- I've also done `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my_email@example.com"` and see the `id_ed25519.pub` file in my `.ssh` folder.

3- I've done `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` and `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519` and have added copied the contents of `id_ed25519.pub` into my Github as an SSH key.

Then when I do

`ssh -T git@github.com`

I get:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.114.4)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,140.82.114.4' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Hi nightfarrow! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

and if I try to do

`sudo git clone --recursive git@github.com:shubham-goel/ucmr.git`

I get that `fatal: Could not read from remote repository.` error.

What might be the issue at this point? How can this problem be diagnosed? Thank you.

Comment: Show whone `git clone` you use.

Comment: `sudo git clone --recursive git@github.com:shubham-goel/ucmr.git` Added this info into OP question now!

Comment: Why `sudo`? ...

Comment: For some reason I actually get `Permission denied` when not having `sudo`, but `sudo -E` as mentioned by the answer does work!

Comment: The "shell access" error is expected. https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're seeing problems because you're using `sudo`.

When you use an SSH key, that comes from your user's home directory, and when you use an SSH agent, that comes from the environment.  When you use `sudo`, you change the current user, so the keys come from root's home directory, and `sudo`, by default, clears the environment for security reasons.  Therefore, there is no possible way to get access to your keys, and your operation fails.

Unless you have a compelling reason, you should avoid `sudo` here because it's not needed.  If you're sure you need it and you're certain that there's nothing in your `PATH` or the rest of the environment that might be a security risk, you can try to use `sudo -E`, which will avoid clearing the environment and therefore let your SSH agent work with your clone.

Comment: `Permission denied` when I try without `sudo`, though... but `sudo -E` works! I wonder what's going on there. Thank you.

Comment: My repo was a web site placed in /var/www (not/home/pi). Thus using sudo was needed to write   in the /var/www  using the git clone command. But the sudo, as explained above, clears the environnement. Thus using sudo -E solve the problem for me: I could git clone my website on my raspberry pi. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I got this issue too and solved it as below..

The only code that solved it for me was to set the remote url on my local machine by copying the ssh url type of my repository; on github presently they are three; Github CLI, Https and SSH and I was initially using Https url before they stopped using password authentication; https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ . So after getting to this point I encountered this error and below code fixed it.

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/your-repository.git`

replace `git@github.com:username/your-repository.git` with your ssh url from git hub.

Answer (score 0):

sudo -E copies the environment variables - If it is configured as an option in the sudoers file.